# Autosys job failing with code C0000374 but process exit with 0 return code

Tags: c++11, autosys

Backend c++ process exit with return code 0 but in autosys job is failing with exit code 3884

[image]
[image]

can someone please tell what could be the possible reason for this job failure.

Comment: where's the code? if there's no code this is more super user question

Comment: @Rutuja - did you figure out what was causing this issue